# Arbitrum: Mapping L2 blocks to L1 batches using RPCs

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc, layer-2, rollups, arbitrum

I'm looking for a way to programmatically map L2 blocks to their corresponding rollup batches in L1 using RPCs.
Is there a way to do this, and if so, what would be the best approach? Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.